# How many times does a given prime occur as factor below a number?

Tags: number-theory

Given an integer $N>0$, a prime $p>2$, what is closed form of the sum $$\large\sum_{\substack{3\,\leq\, m\,\leq\, N\\p^i\mid m\strut\\{m\bmod p^{i+1}}\,\neq\,0}}i$$ which is ${j:\substack{p^j\mid N!\\ N!\bmod p^{j+1}\,\neq\,0\strut}}$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are asking for the largest $k$ such that $p^k|N!$, correct?

Comment: Yes that is right!

Comment: I'm sure there is a duplicate somewhere that answers just that question (it is commonly given specifically as $p=5$ asking for "how many zeroes at the end of $n!$").  Look at the multiples of $p$ that are less than $N$.  Then look at the multiples of $p^2$, the multiples of $p^3$, etc...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula.  An equivalent expression for the sum you're looking for is $(N - d_p(N))/(p-1)$ where $d_p$ is the sum of all the digits of $N$ when expressed in base $p$.

Comment: @ErickWong Could you explain proof of your formula in answer?

Comment: @ErickWong So largest $j$ satisfying $p^j|N!$ is $\frac{N−d_p(N)}{p−1}$ where $d_p$ is sum of all digits of $N$ expressed in base $p$?

Comment: @Turbo Yup.  It's not too hard to prove (that it's equal to the sum in JMoravitz's answer) by first considering the case where $N = d\cdot p^r$ where $d < p$ so that $N$ has only one non-zero digit, and then showing that the contributions from different digits don't interact much.

Comment: @Turbo See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977053/calculating-the-power-of-prime-in-factorial-by-changing-base

Comment: @ErickWong Could you repost answer here for completeness. I will close question.

Answer (score 1):

The result will be:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{N}{p^n}\right\rfloor$$

The reason being that there will be $\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\rfloor$ numbers in $\{1,\dots,N\}$ that are divisible by $p$ (which is the same number that are in $\{3,4,\dots,N\}$ in the case that $p>2$).

Similarly, there will be $\lfloor\frac{N}{p^2}\rfloor$ numbers in $\{1,\dots,N\}$ which are divisible by $p^2$.  Normally, you would think that you want to add two to the overall total for each of these, however we already added one for each when we did $\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\rfloor$, so each of those multiples of $p^2$ (which are not multiples of $p^3$) have the correct number added so far.

Similarly correct the count for those multiples of $p^3,p^4,\dots$ by repeatedly adding yet another one to the total for each, yielding the final expression as given above.

Comment: You are just rewriting what I told. I am looking for a closed form.

Comment: @Turbo This is about as closed a form as you'll get.  Given a specific $p$ and $N$, it is a trivial task to calculate this sum.  As for a "closed form," keep in mind that this function has multiple jumps depending on how close $N$ is to multiples of powers of $p$.  Are you looking instead for an estimate?

Comment: ErickWong has an answer " An equivalent expression for the sum you're looking for is (N−dp(N))/(p−1) where dp is the sum of all the digits of N when expressed in base p. "